# addition instead of subtraction in Kahan algorithm

Tags: c++, floating-point, sum, ieee-754, rounding-error

This is the [Kahan summation algorithm from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm):

```
function KahanSum(input)
    var sum = 0.0
    var c = 0.0
    for i = 1 to input.length do
        y = input[i] - c    // why subtraction?
        t = sum + y
        c = (t - sum) - y
        sum = t
    return sum
```

Is there a specific reason why it uses subtraction (as opposed to addition)? If I swap the operands in the computation of `c`, can I use addition instead? Somehow, that would make more sense to me:

```
function KahanSum(input)
    var sum = 0.0
    var c = 0.0
    for i = 1 to input.length do
        y = input[i] + c    // addition instead of subtraction
        t = sum + y
        c = y - (t - sum)   // swapped operands
        sum = t
    return sum
```

Or is there some weird difference between floating point addition and subtraction I don't know about yet?

Also, is there any difference between `(t - sum) - y` and `t - sum - y` in the original algorithm? Aren't the parenthesis redundant, since `-` is left-associative, anyway?

Comment: I am sure you have, but still, have you tested to see if use of addition actually gives you the same result. also, have tried benchmarking to get a rough idea of what is faster?

Comment: Easiest to just compare the assemblies. Would you have asked why it isn't subtraction if the second version had been the one on Wikipedia?

Comment: Fred, have you read the last section of the Wikipedia page you are referring to? It seems to explain the reason for the parentheses. Taking a different example, `a+b+c` can be computed as `(a+b)+c` or as `a+(b+c)` and the results could be different. There could be something similar in this case, for example, `a-b-c` can be computed as `(a-b)-c` but also as `a-(b+c)` leading to different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your method is exactly equivalent to the one from Wikipedia. The only difference is that the sign of `c` -- and therefore its meaning -- is reversed. In the Wikipedia algorithm, `c` is the "wrong" part of the sum; c=0.0001 means that the sum is a little bigger than it should be. In your version, `c` is the "correction" to the sum; c=-0.0001 means that the sum should be made a little smaller.

And I think the parentheses are for readability. They're for us, not the machine.

Comment: There exist programming languages in which the parentheses are necessary, because a compiler is allowed to re-associate a sum as it sees fit.

Comment: @StephenCanon why would parentheses help with such languages? If the compiler is free to associate according to the rules of infinite-precision arithmetic, then parentheses won't change the compiler's behavior.

Comment: @Ruslan: In fortran, for example, the compiler is allowed to re-associate un-parenthesized expressions, but must respect parentheses if they are present.

Answer (score 2):

Your two algorithms are equivalent. The only difference during execution will be the sign of `c`. The reason it uses addition is because in Kahan's version, `c` represents the error, which is conventionally the correct minus the computed value.

In the sense that parentheses specify the order of operations, the parentheses are absolutely necessary. In fact, they are what makes this algorithm work!

When subtraction is left-associative, as it is in most languages, `a - b - c` evaluates as `(a - b) - c` so the two are the same. But the subtraction in the Kahan algorithm is `a - (b - c)`, and that should *not* be evaluated as `a - b + c`.

Floating-point addition and subtraction are not associative. For expressions that are equivalent in standard arithmetic, you may get different results depending on the order in which you perform the operations.

Let's work with 3 decimal digits of precision, for the sake of clarity. This means that if we get a result with 4 digits, we have to round it. 
Now compare `(a - b) - c` with the mathematically equivalent `a - (b + c)` for some specific values:

```
(998 - 997) - 5 = 1 - 5 = -4
```

with

```
998 - (997 + 5) = 998 - Round(1002)
                = 998 - 1000 = -2
```

So the second approach is less accurate.

In the Kahan algorithm, `t` and `sum` will usually be relatively large compared to `y`. So you often get a situation like in the example above where you would get a less accurate result if you don't do the operations in the correct order.

Comment: In C, the parentheses are unnecessary.  `a - b - c` explicitly means `(a - b) - c`.  This is not true for all programming languages.

Comment: @Jeffrey: The `-` *operation* is **never** associative, not even for integers. However, the `-` *operator* is **always** right-associative, that is, `a - b - c` means `(a - b) - c`.

Comment: @Stephen: In what programming language does `a - b - c` mean `a - (b - c)`?

Comment: @Fred By addition and subtraction not being associative, I meant that when mixing addition and subtraction, the order of evaluation matters. Also, `a - b - c = (a - b) - c` is called _left_-associative because it is evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't know of any language where `a - b - c` means `a - (b - c)` -- that would be ridiculous.  However, there do exist languages in which a compiler is licensed to transform `a - b - c` into `a - (b + c)`.  Fortran is an example.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Of course I meant left-associative, exactly as I stated in the question :)